# Can I leave a coolant leak for a month if I won't be driving my car?

Tags: coolant-leak

Yesterday I found a leak under my car and the coolant is very low. I won't be driving my car for 4-6 weeks because of an operation. Am I able to hold off getting the leak fixed until after that without damaging anything further? (It's a long weekend so no mechanics are open and then my operation is the next day)

Also the leak is to the right of the car a little behind the front tire, anyway to know if that is just a hose or the whole radiator needs replacing ? The leak is quite fast.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 4):

What  you're describing is usually where the drain is for the A/C core. Humidity collects on the evaporator core, then gets collected, then drains out through this tube. If the radiator is a bit low, then refill it with 50/50 premix and call it a day. Leaving it sit will not cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Letting a coolant leak sit while not using the vehicle will not be an issue for the vehicle, providing you fill to the right level range before starting again.

However, ethylene glycol, if that is a component in your coolant, is extremely toxic and can impact wildlife and pets.  It has a sweet taste, although some more current formulations have additives to make the taste more objectionable, particularly to children.

If you are not driving the vehicle, check under it after 2 or 3 days and see if the wet spot is still there.  If not, it is likely you were witnessing some other fluid, such as condensate from the automotive air conditioning evaporator.